# Display legend in a stacked bar chart using ngx-echarts in Angular

Tags: angular, echarts, ngx-echarts

I have a stacked bar chart which contains different categories of data based on month. I'm displaying it as a stacked bar chart, but I also need to display the legend to go along with the data so that each color is understandable.

[The chart looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZA2J.png)

I have tried defining the legend in different ways, for example like this:

```
legend: {
        data: this.categoryArray,
        orient: 'vertical',
        right: 10,
        show: true
      }
```

where categoryArray is a simple string array containing all the different categories of data.

Despite this, my chart appears without a legend. Does anyone know how I can actually display the legend along with the chart itself? Thanks.

Comment: In order to assist you it would be helpful if you share your code. It sounds to me like you want to use a [visual map](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Visual%20Map%20of%20Data) ([docs](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#visualMap-piecewise)). Here is an [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=heatmap-large-piecewise) displaying how the legend could look like.

Comment: @MatthiasMertens I included a picture of the chart I have. The rest of the code should be irrelevant for this question, as all I am looking for is displaying the names of the categories corresponding to the colors displayed in the chart.

Comment: `legend: {}` should be enough if you name each series. You can also take a look at [this example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-y-category-stack) .

Comment: @MatthiasMertens Thanks you for your answer! I had somehow missed the name-parameter when creating the series :/